# Avoid lots of \text{} commands in formulas

Tags: equations, text-mode

I am working on typing a document with a lot of formulas which have words in them. I know I can use `\text{}` from the AMS package to make the word appear normally in the equation, but I was wondering if there was a less cumbersome way to do this when I have many words in the same formula. Is there a way to set all the characters in a formula to appear normally or else some less obtrusive way to accomplish this?

Example:

```
$\sigma_{\text{type}=\text{'single'} \, \text{AND} \, \text{price} < 20}(\text{Room})$
```

Comment: Help us out with some specific examples.  For example, is this what you are looking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/how-do-i-produce-an-equation-of-mostly-text-that-is-not-too-long-for-the-page

Comment: Welcome! Can you give an example? If *all* the characters should appear normally, you can just stay in text mode. So it isn't really clear what you mean.

Comment: You can group words in `\text`: `\text{some text here }`.

Comment: BTW, `\text` if for 'real' texxt inside moth mode: things like identifiers should use `\mathrm` or similar.

Comment: @JosephWright What counts as 'real' or not exactly?

Comment: That naming method is quite bad. If somewhere else needs to use the variable, the whole equation would be too long.

Comment: @cfr As always, it's not a clear distinction and there would be always opinions. Personally, I usually think, as a rule of thumb, that text is what connects differents parts of math, that I can't “escape” by using `$` because I'm in display math mode or because I'm inside a group/box, etc. hence I have to use `\text` rather than ending temporarily math mode.

Comment: @Stan Which naming method?

Comment: @cfr I meant the naming method for variable subscripts in that document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80344/indirectly-defining-two-active-characters-within-an-atbegindocument-command), here we use `*` instead of `<` which is frequently used in math mode.

Just add your text in math mode like `*text*`, if you which to use character `*` outside math mode you can do it with the restoration of its code number inside a group.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\catcode`\*=13
\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\*
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~#1*}{\text{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\sigma_{*type*=*'single'* \, *AND* \, *price* < 20}(*Room*)$

{\catcode`\*=12 text*} 

$\sigma_{*type*=*'single'* \, *AND* \, *price* < 20}(*Room*)$

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Thanks to @egreg suggestion replacing `\catcode` with `\mathcode` to avoid changing code number of `*` every time outside math mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mathcode`*="8000
\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\*
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~#1*}{\text{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\sigma_{*type*=*'single'* \, *AND* \, *price* < 20}(*Room*)$

text* 

$\sigma_{*type*=*'single'* \, *AND* \, *price* < 20}(*Room*)$

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What about `\section*{Introduction}`? (It won't work.) You should say ``\mathcode`*="8000``, rather than ``\catcode`*=13`` (and `\textnormal` rather than `\text`).

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it works, but this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create new command by \newcommand (or \renewcommand if they exist) to make text subscripts. I think something like `\newcommand{\pippo}[1]{{}_\text{#1}}` could work.. (I cannot try now, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Some things appear the same (or almost the same) in text and math modes, so for this example you could simply use

```
$\sigma_{\text{type = `single' AND price $<$ 20}}$(Room)
```

[image: all text]

or

```
$\sigma_{\text{type$\strut =\strut$`single' AND price$\strut <20$}}$(Room)
```

[image: math mode separation]